# How to create dynamic controls on the fly in asp.net;IndexChanged Event on dropdowns does not persist/fire after post back

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have

> several dynamic drop downs

with selected index changed event attached to them but what happens is once the index change event is triggered for the first time and once the postback  is completed they lose that indexchange event but not the item values

> so its saving the state of the dropdowns but not attaching the
>   selected index change event on a post back.

**AspxPage:**

```
 <div>
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="mp_1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </div>
```

**C#:**

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void ddl_IndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write("dsfsdf");
        }           

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

 DropDownList ddl_1 = new DropDownList();
                ddl_1.ID = "ddl_1";
                ddl_1.AutoPostBack = true;
                ddl_1.EnableViewState = true;
                ddl_1.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ddl_IndexChanged);
                this.mp_1.Controls.Add(ddl_1); 


            if(!IsPostBack)
            {
                DropDownList ddl_1 = (DropDownList)Page.FindControl("ddl_1");
                if (ddl_1 != null)
                {
                    List<ListItem> items = new List<ListItem>();
                    items.Add(new ListItem("Item 2", "Value 2"));
                    items.Add(new ListItem("Item 1", "Value 1"));
                    items.Add(new ListItem("Item 3", "Value 3"));
                    ddl_1.Items.AddRange(items.ToArray());
                }                
            }               
        }
    }
```

Comment: If your controls don't exist on postback they can't hit the event handelers, remove `if(!Page.IsPostBack)` and try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**AspxPage:**

```
 <div>
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="mp_1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </div>
```

**C#:**

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DropDownList ddl_1 = new DropDownList();
            ddl_1.ID = "ddl_1";
            ddl_1.AutoPostBack = true;
            ddl_1.EnableViewState = true;
            ddl_1.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ddl_IndexChanged);
            this.mp_1.Controls.Add(ddl_1); 
        }

        private void ddl_IndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write("dsfsdf");
        }           

        // add entries in page load method not in init method
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(!IsPostBack)
            {
                DropDownList ddl_1 = (DropDownList)Page.FindControl("ddl_1");
                if (ddl_1 != null)
                {
                    List<ListItem> items = new List<ListItem>();
                    items.Add(new ListItem("Item 2", "Value 2"));
                    items.Add(new ListItem("Item 1", "Value 1"));
                    items.Add(new ListItem("Item 3", "Value 3"));
                    ddl_1.Items.AddRange(items.ToArray());
                }                
            }               
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Most stable way to create and bind dynamic child controls would be to override CreateChildControls method:

[See official sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.createchildcontrols%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)